# Place Google Drive Folder on Timecapsule

Tags: google-drive, time-capsule

Is there a way to have the Google Drive folder inside Apple Time Capsule ?

When I try, I keep getting:

1. I initially go to google drive application setup;
2. I then select a folder on my Time Capsule;
3. I get:

   > "The folder `/somepath/Google Drive` can't be used.  Please select another folder."

What can I do to have a Google Drive folder in Time capsule?

Comment: Have you read this question: http://superuser.com/questions/416294/can-i-sync-network-folder-with-a-google-drive?rq=1 and this question: http://superuser.com/questions/422650/change-local-google-drive-folder?rq=1 by chance?

Comment: I've done that. No avail.

Comment: Please include the things you have tried. What exactly did you do? What does "to no avail" mean? How did it fail? What error messages or strange behavior are you getting?

Comment: The error message is there already. :/ I will precise the steps.

Comment: The error message is not there, it may depend on the specific path. How are you giving the Time Capsule's address? How is it mounted? Smb? AFP? NFS? What Operating System are you using?

Comment: @terdon: mac os x lion; NFS+ (so I believe, cause I can't seem to find where to see Time Capsule disk partition information). I'm copy pasting, (mouse) so no wrong address. thanks